# ReactJS state update and immediate access

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

```
onContactChange = (contactInfo) => {
if (!this.state.isRecipientSelected) {
  this.setState({ ...this.state, isRecipientSelected: true });
}
if (contactInfo.selectedContactAccount.type && this.state.isRecipientSelected) {
  //...
```

In above code segment isRecipientSelected set True then immediately access its value inside the next if clause's condition. In ReactJs setState is asynchronous so i assume when access the value immediately inside the second if clause isRecipientSelected value might remain unchanged.

Is my  assumption correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since setState is an synchronous function, it is better to use a callback function in the setState which will only be called after the state is set. In your case:

```
if (!this.state.isRecipientSelected) {
  this.setState({ ...this.state, isRecipientSelected: true },function(){
      //Rest of the code
   }
);
}
```

Comment: `onContactChange = (contactInfo) => {
       let recipientSelected = this.state.isRecipientSelected;     
if (!recipientSelected) {
       recipientSelected = true;       
this.setState({ ...this.state, isRecipientSelected: recipientSelected });     
}     
if (contactInfo.selectedContactAccount.type && recipientSelected) {`
  
Thanks confirming my assumption, here i fixed it using a new variable. As you mention, using the callback would be ideal for things need to be done after state is set.