# React update state array in useEffect hook

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state, use-effect, setstate

I've read all the questions and answers about setting State on an array in React but none seem to fix my issue.

I initialise my arrays like this:

```js
 const initialStates = {cellStatuses: () =>Array(6).fill(Array(5).fill(status.unguessed)),
} 
const [dailyCellStatuses, setDailyCellStatuses] = useLocalStorage('dailyCellStatuses', initialStates.cellStatuses)

const [cellStatuses, setCellStatuses] = useState(initialStates.cellStatuses)
```

and then later I use an effect to mimic componentDidMount and in that effect I check if the cellStatuses need to be updated

```
useEffect (() => {
    if (gameMode && playedAlreadyToday(lastPlayedDate)) {
      setBoard(dailyBoard)
      setCellStatuses(dailyCellStatuses)
      console.log(cellStatuses, 'cell statuses')
    } else {
      setBoard(initialStates.board)
    }
```

The console always logs the old state it never updates with the new dailyCellStatuses that I am trying to set.
I have tried cloning the dailyCellStatuses `[...dailyCellStatuses]`
I have tried calling a function in the setter
I'm really stuck. Help!

Comment: React state updates are not immediate ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS state update and immediate access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66899130/reactjs-state-update-and-immediate-access)

Comment: Thanks I don't think so. 

I tried it out anyway and put the console statement into a callback function and it produced this error ```State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your state is updating fine, your issue is you are console logging the value in the same render cycle,

Console log the value outside useEffect or you can do this

```
    if (gameMode && playedAlreadyToday(lastPlayedDate)) {
      setBoard(dailyBoard)
      setCellStatuses(dailyCellStatuses)
      console.log(dailyCellStatuses, 'cell statuses')
    } else {
      setBoard(initialStates.board)
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I thought the same.  But its not so. 

When I console.log the new board value I see it behaving as expected. 
Also when I check dev tools Components state I can see that the old state is still there.   I'm really stumped.

Comment: I found my problem.  I have another effect that is acting on the cellstatuses.  you are correct the code above is working, but I have a side effect elsewhere undoing my setStatuses.

Comment: gotcha.........